# quota between onedrive and onedrive for business

Tags: office365, onedrive

I am confused about the quota used between onedrive and onedrive for business.

If I have 1TB quota cause of the onedrive for business, does this space is combined with onedrive personal?

Or these two space are separated, onedrive stands for 15GB, onedrive for business stands for 1TB?

If these two space are combined together, could I use live sdk to retrieve the data from my onedrive, or I need to use office365 api to do.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

OneDrive for Business and OneDrive are two entirely separate products. The space allocation is different - if you have 1 TB for OneDrive for Business, it means you have 1 TB only for OneDrive for Business.

You need to use the live API to retrieve data from OneDrive, and the Office 365 Files API to retrieve data from OneDrive for Business.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft complicates things to the point of absurdity.

Onedrive for Business is Sharepoint. You CANNOT use ODforB without using Sharepoint they are one and the same. Microsoft may have put some grey areas in here just to lose customers (unwillingly) but thinking of ODforB of anything other than Sharepoint will confuse you to the point of ditching the service.

Also there is a 50k file limit on the drive. So its not really 1TB...

Log into 365 online and go to SHAREPOINT and you will then be able to sync with the ODB folder and use ODforB (Sharepoint).